# Javascript variable only getting first word of string

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am doing a basic Javascript function at the moment and in a bit of brain fog so any help is appreciated. I know it's most likely a syntax error...

I have a select value containing a PHP variable that is being passed to a javascript function. When I console.log the variable for results, I am only getting the first word of the string. For example, if the company name is 'my new company' I get 'my' in the console.
HTML:

```
<select name="company[]" id="company'.$rowId.'" onChange="companyJobList(this.value)">';

            $sqlC ="SELECT DISTINCT(companyName) 
            FROM customers 
            WHERE invoice = '1'
            ORDER BY companyName ASC";
            $resultC = $conn -> query($sqlC);
            echo '<option disabled selected="selected">Select company</option><option></option>';
            while ($companies=$resultC->fetch_assoc()) {
            
                echo '<option value= '.$companies['companyName'].'>'.$companies['companyName'].' </option>';
            }

            echo'       
                </select>
```

Javascript:

```
function companyJobList(a){
    console.log(a);
}
```

Comment: Please show the rendered output from the PHP script since that is where we can see the values that are being produced.

Comment: The output on the drop-down shows the full name in the PHP variable. So for instance 'my new company' is shown correctly in the dropdown. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: No, Please edit your question and show the code that is produced after the PHP has rendered the resulting HTML .

Comment: Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem? Please share more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typo:

```
<option value= my company name>my company name</option>
```

is missing quotation marks and sets the `value` attribute to "my". Inserting the missing quotes (in the `echo` statement in PHP) so it produces

```
<option value="my company name">my company name</option>
```

should fix the problem.

Any double quotation marks in the company name also **need to be replaced** by the HTML character entity `&quot;` to prevent quote marks in the name  prematurely terminating the value attribute.

Comment: I changed my code to the following to solve the issue. Thank you for the help...  <option value="<?php echo $companies['companyName'] ?>"><?php echo $companies['companyName'] ?></option>